# Accidentally disabling evil mode in spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, evil

While use spacemacs in evil mode, I sometimes accidentally disable evil mode and I do not understand how I am doing it. And once disabled, I do not know how to reenable the mode without restarting emacs.

1. Any idea what I am doing?
2. How do I reenable evil mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I am hitting `C-z`, which toggles between Evil and Emacs mode.

Comment: `SPC t E e` also toggles into Emacs mode, but its probably more likely you're just hitting `C-z` ;)